# Angular 2 : iterator1.next is not a function at Object.areIterablesEqual Error

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angular-cli

I use angular 2 rc4 and angular cli with firebase in ubuntu 14.04 : 
and i get this error :

```
 browser_adapter.ts:82 TypeError: iterator1.next is not a function
     at Object.areIterablesEqual (collection.ts:316)
     at Object.devModeEqual (change_detection_util.ts:18)
     at checkBinding (view_utils.ts:144)
     at DebugAppView._View_MdSidenavLayout0.detectChangesInternal (MdSidenavLayout.template.js:64)
     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:261)
     at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:377)
     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (view.ts:288)
     at DebugAppView._View_EveyWebAppComponent0.detectChangesInternal(EveyWebAppComponent.template.js:678)
     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:261)
     at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:377)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:82
 browser_adapter.ts:82 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:82
```